# How do I validate an unsaved grid record when taking a header off hold?

Tags: acumatica

I have a header/line structure on a screen that needs to allow a lot of flexibility when entering data but prevent taking the record off hold until all line items have an inventory id.  At the time the record is created, an inventory id may not exist, so I can't make the inventory id field required at initial entry.

I expected that PXSelect would pull any new records from the database but hold onto the currently cached data from entry.  What I found instead was that entry of a new line item does not appear to be accessed via the PXSelect until I save the record.  That means unchecking Hold ignores the inventory ID that I see on-screen, and the code below gives generates the exception for "NoInventoryID".

```
#region MyHdr_Hold_FieldVerifying
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldVerifying<MyHdr.hold> e)
{
    if ((bool?)e.NewValue == true) return;

    MyHdr row = (MyHdr)e.Row;

    MyLine line =
    PXSelect<MyLine, Where<MyLine.hdrID, Equal<Current<MyHdr.hdrID>>>>
        .SelectSingleBound(this, new object[] { e.Row });
    if (line == null)
        throw new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.NoLines, PXErrorLevel.Warning);

    line =
    PXSelect<MyLine, Where<MyLine.hdrID, Equal<Current<MyHdr.hdrID>>, And<MyLine.inventoryID, NotEqual<Null>>>>
        .SelectSingleBound(this, new object[] { e.Row });
    if (line != null)
        throw new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.NoInventoryID, PXErrorLevel.Warning);
}
#endregion
```

I have CommitChanges = True on the Inventory ID field, so it seems a special technique is required to validate the grid lines when validating the header hold field.

How do I look into the unsaved data on the grid (child lines of the header) to validate without making the user persist the records first?

Comment: You can do dataview.Select() or check in the Inserted/Updated collections of Caches[typeof(DAC)].Inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the name of the data view:
[image]

You then call the Select method of the data view to get the records.

For new graph inheriting from PXGraph:

```
foreach (SOLine line in Transactions.Select())
{
}
```

For graph extensions inheriting from PXGraphExtension you need to add the Base prefix:

```
foreach (SOLine line in Base.Transactions.Select())
{
}
```

For data views that contain multiple DACs, you can access them with PXResult.

```
> PXSelect<DAC1, InnerJoin<DAC2>, LeftJoin<DAC3>>

foreach (PXResult<DAC1, DAC2, DAC3> results in DataView.Select())
{
    DAC1 dac1 = (DAC1)results;
    DAC2 dac2 = (DAC2)results;
    DAC3 dac3 = (DAC3)results;
}
```

Finally, all data displayed on screen should be in one of the cache collections.
This one also need to be prefixed by Base if used in the context of a graph extension:

```
foreach (SOLine line in Caches[typeof(SOLine)].Inserted)
{
}

foreach (SOLine line in Caches[typeof(SOLine)].Updated)
{
}
```

Comment: This was working great until we noticed that there is a way to break it.  We are validating when taking the header off of hold.  When the line value being validated is keyed and then the user leaves the field, taking off hold validates properly. When it is entered and then the next physical action is to go straight to clicking on the hold checkbox, it does not detect that the value was updated in the line.  It seems like the only possible work around is to put commit changes on all fields to be validated, but I'm not sure that will work either.  Is this an Acumatica bug or something I'm doing?

Comment: To get any code executed in the graph requires a callback. To get a callback requires CommitChanges. So it sounds like that would be the only way. Otherwise you could let the user do the hold operation and cancel it in FieldUpdated event handler.

Comment: I was doing that in the field verifying event and could not see the entered value.  Are you saying that the field will commit where I can check if so do it in field updated on the hold field which has the commit changes?  I think this is touching in one of the finer points I still struggle with on how events fire and what impact they have on the other views.

Comment: HB, I'm missing something and not really sure what to ask... Commit Changes didn't work for me if I set the Qty field in the detail level grid row and immediately go uncheck hold in the header.  If I change to Events.FieldUpdated<MyDAC.hold> then I can throw an exception, but MyDAC.hold does not refresh until I save the record (which works because the hold checkbox is checked in memory but not on the screen.  I'm on 19.110.0013, and this feels like an Acumatica bug, but I cannot swear by it.

Comment: JavaScript events ain't very reliable, if you focus control X and click on action button I've seen the events not fire. There's no way around it currently, if you 'tab' out of control X before clicking on hold checkbox I suspect that works.